# faster alternatives to sparse.model.matrix?

Tags: r, categorical-data, representation

I have a large dataset that is entirely categorical. I'm trying to train with it using xgboost, so I must first convert this categorical data to numerical. So far I've been using sparse.model.matrix() in the Matrix library but it is far too slow. I found a great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035982/directly-creating-dummy-variable-set-in-a-sparse-matrix-in-r), however, the sparse matrix it returns in not the same one that sparse.model.matrix returns. I know there is a way to force sparse.model.matrix to return identical output as the solution in the link ([by providing contrasts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560459/all-levels-of-a-factor-in-a-model-matrix-in-r/4569239#4569239), however, that is not an effective solution as it is still too slow and results in different representation (and hence different training model).

Is there a way to accomplish the job sparse.model.matrix does even nearly as fast as the solution I posted? For my data, the solution I posted does it in about 15% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try that but remove LHS variables from dataset before hands? We use that for the data processing part of putting our xgboost models in production.

```
fspmatrix <- function(df) {
  # Building sparse matrix with sparseMatrix to save time vs sparse.model.matrix

  # Details about the df to help build triplet
  nr <- nrow(df)
  nc <- ncol(df)
  nlevels <- pmax(1, sapply(df, nlevels))
  fac <- which(sapply(df, is.factor))
  # Check that all factors have at least 2 levels
  stopifnot(min(nlevels[fac]) > 1)

  # Building the value vector removing zero positions and first levels of factors after the first factor
  x <- as.numeric(unlist(unlist(df)))
  jx <- x # for use in building j
  # Positions of values coming from factors
  pos <- as.vector(sapply(fac * nr, function(x) x - nr + (1:nr)))
  # Positions of first levels of factors after the first factor
  pos1 <- pos[-1:-nr]
  pos1 <- pos1[which(x[pos1] == 1)]
  # Replacing the values of factors with 1 for one hot encoding
  x[pos] <- 1
  # Positions of non-zero values
  nzpos <- which(x[-pos1] != 0)
  # Values to build triplet around
  x <- x[-pos1][nzpos]

  # Building the i vector, the first dim part of the triplet
  i <- rep(seq_len(nr), nc)[-pos1][nzpos]

  # Building the j vector, the second dim part of the triplet
  jnlevels <- nlevels
  jnlevels[fac[-1]] <- jnlevels[fac[-1]] - 1
  jx[-pos] <- 1
  jx[pos[-1:-nr]] <- jx[pos[-1:-nr]] - 1
  cs <- cumsum(c(0, head(jnlevels, -1)))
  j <- jx + rep(cs, each = nr)
  j <- j[-pos1][nzpos]

  # Building the dimnames vector
  tag <- TRUE
  fspnames <- as.vector(unlist(sapply(names(df), function(n) {
    clvl <- as.character(levels(df[[n]]))
    isL <- is.logical(df[[n]])
    isF <- is.factor(df[[n]])
    indx <- if (tag & isF) {
      1:length(clvl)
    } else {
      -1
    }
    if (tag & isF) tag <<- FALSE
    paste0(n, clvl[indx], ifelse(isL, "TRUE", ""))
  })))

  fspm <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = x, dims = c(nr, tail(cs, 1) + tail(jnlevels, 1)), dimnames = list(NULL, fspnames))

  return(fspm)
}
```